# Why isn't array element overwritten with this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm asked to solve the following problem:

Write a function that takes in a string of one or more words, and returns the same string, but with all five or more letter words reversed. Strings passed in will consist of only letters and spaces. Spaces will be included only when more than one word is present.

I've come up with this solution:

```
function spinWords(input) {
  if (input.length < 5) {
    return input;
  }

  let arrayOfWords = input.split(' ');

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfWords.length; i++) {
    let word = arrayOfWords[i];
    if (word.length >= 5) {
        arrayOfWords[i] = word.split('').reverse().join('');
    }
  }

  return arrayOfWords.join(' ');
}
```

Initially, I'd written the body of the if-statement in the for-loop this way (which did not work):

`word = word.split('').reverse().join('')`

I'm confused as to why the former works properly, but the latter does not. Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `word = word.split('').reverse().join('')` means that each next word is copied in the variable `word` but is not modified *in place* within `arrayOfWords`.
As `arrayOfWords` is the list of the initial words, `arrayOfWords[i] = word.split('').reverse().join('')` will modify/overwrite each word as you expected.

---

Besides, here's an optimized version of `spinWords` function:

```js
function spinWords(input) {
    var input = input.trim();
    if (input.length < 5) {
        return input;
    }

    return input.split(' ').map(function(w) {
        return (w.length >= 5 && w.split('').reverse().join('')) || w;
    }).join(' ');                    
}

var str = 'what should I do in this world of mysery';
console.log(spinWords(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let word = arrayOfWords[i];
```

So in here, the word is string copied from the ith element in the array. When you reassign

```
word = word.split('').reverse().join('')
```

like this, this just makes the word (new variable that you made as string) as reversed word not the actual element in the original array. I hope it helps.